# Rails: How can I write a path to the current page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, path, routes

How can I create a path that redirects back to the current page?

Eg. I'm on `http://example/users/3` , I click on the link, and it redirects me to `http://example/users/3`.

This seems like it should be very simple, but I can't find anything online and all my guesses return an 'undefined method' error.

I'm trying to print erb into an href link, so I think it has to be a path... something along the lines of

```
href="facebook/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= path_to_current_url %>"
```

If it matters, I'm using Rails 4.0.10.

Comment: you click on what link?

Comment: That's the question. Something I tried was <%= link_to "Refresh", current_path %> but current_path returned an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
request.original_url
```

This will get the absolute url.
Documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I'm trying to print the url with erb, so I think it has to be a path.

Comment: Check edits Please, let me know if that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use  request.env['REQUEST_URI'] to get the url as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<%= link_to "Refresh", '#' %>`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I'm trying to print the url with erb, so I think it has to be a path.